# Two rep-counts on my profile's "tags" tab work seem to be "stuck" somehow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, reputation, profile-page

My [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) scores on the "tags" tab in my SO profile appear to be "stuck" at 972 and 957 respectively, despite the fact that I've definitely received a net increase in rep for both tags (on non-wiki questions) over the **week or two** that I've been watching this phenomenon.

Is there something wrong, or am I just missing something obvious?

I am aware that tag scores are cached to one-day resolution.

Obviously it's frustrating to be so close to two gold badges, and yet, *so very far*.

Comment: Oh hey.. it means answer _score_ not _rep_, doesn't it. They have slightly changed now. I guess I didn't notice the _tiny_ increments mostly because I was expecting them to be larger.